# Creation multimap throught lambda-expression

Tags: java, lambda

I am reading a book "Effective Java" and coming up with fragmnet of code:

```
public enum Phase {

    SOLID, LIQUID, GAS;

    public enum Transition {
     
        MELT(SOLID, LIQUID), FREEZE(LIQUID, SOLID)
        BOIL(LIQUID, GAS), CONDENSE(GAS, LIQUID), 
        SUBLIME(SOLID, GAS), DEPOSIT(GAS, SOLID);

        private final Phase from;
        private final Phase to;

        Transition(Phase from, Phase to) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        private static final Map<Phase, Map<Phase, Transition>> m = 
        Stream.of(values())
              .collect(groupingBy(t -> t.from, 
                                 () -> new EnumMap<>(Phase.class), 
                                 toMap(t -> t.to, t -> t, (x, y) -> 
                                 y, () -> new EnumMap<> 
                                 (Phase.class)))));

        public static Transition from(Phase from, Phase to) {
            return m.get(from).get(to);
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't understand lambda expression details helping to create such a multimap: I mean what does command  `toMap(t -> t.to, t -> t, (x, y) -> y, () -> new EnumMap<>(Phase.class)))));` make? Perhaphs, I am silly, but this is really difficult to me.
What I do understand:

1. Expression `Stream.of(values())` creates and returns an array of `enum Transition` elements
2. Expression `t -> t.from` merely means that each element of `enum Transition` array, returning by command `Stream.of(values())` maps to `Phase from` element.
3. Expression `() -> new EnumMap<>(Phase.class)` probably means that there is to be created map for each `Phase from` element.
4. Here I am at stupor.

Comment: Have you looked at the Javadoc of [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F21%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier))?

Comment: I haven't looked toMap() tutorial, but, according to its name, this method creates a map!

Comment: Read the whole documentation.  It tells you everything that's going on.  In general, before asking StackOverflow what some piece of code is doing, try looking at the documentation.

Comment: Is this code difficult or not?